# Power BI - Calculate average for measure with selected values

Tags: charts, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have a table with dataset, I need create visual with slicers over time, where i can select 1st item and 2nd item and calculated delta between them.

I’ve done that by create 2 tables with Dax

```
test_item_1 = values('tbl_data'[Item])
test_item_2 = values('tbl_data'[Item])
```

Add 2 slicers with list of items for 1 and 2.

Then in table - tbl_data, create new measure to calculate delta between selected items in slicers  over time

```
test_delta = calculate(sum('tbl_data'[Value]),'tbl_data'[Item] = SELECTEDVALUE(test_item_1[Item 1])) - calculate(sum('tbl_data'[Value]),'tbl_data'[Item] = SELECTEDVALUE(test_item_2[Item 2]))
```

Could you please advise how to create Average based on calculated delta for all selected datetime period.

Chart supposed to be like that as example.

[image]

| Date | Item | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-04-27 | item_1 | 20 |
| 2023-04-26 | item_1 | 30 |
| 2023-04-25 | item_1 | 40 |
| 2023-04-24 | item_1 | 50 |
| 2023-04-27 | item_2 | 100 |
| 2023-04-26 | item_2 | 110 |
| 2023-04-25 | item_2 | 120 |
| 2023-04-24 | item_2 | 130 |
| 2023-04-27 | item_3 | 150 |
| 2023-04-26 | item_3 | 160 |
| 2023-04-25 | item_3 | 170 |
| 2023-04-24 | item_3 | 180 |

I'm able to get and calculate delta but don't know how to calculate average for that delta as a single line.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following measure:

```
=
CALCULATE (
    DIVIDE (
        [test_delta],
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( tbl_data[Date] )
    ),
    ALL ( tbl_data[Date] )
)
```